# Adding object to navigation property collection creates new entity

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4.

I am trying to associate a new entity with an existing entity.  The system ends up creating a new child entity when in fact I just want to add a reference to the child object to the parent.

There is a many to many relationship between the two entities so I cannot simply set the FK property of the parent entity.  I have tried parent.ChildCollection.Add(child) which simply creates a new child object in the database.  This is what I am trying to avoid.

I must be doing something obviously wrong.

thanks

**updated code sample**

Code sample for my Self-Tracking-Entities that I have to do client side
Right now I have something like this to get all children from server then loop through to find the one i want, then add it to the object collection

```
          List<Service.Child> childs = _client.GetChildren();
```

I have to loop through that collection to find the right one to add to the parent.childs collection ie.

```
            List<Service.Child> childList = new List<Service.Child>();
            foreach (Service.Child child in childList) {
                if (child.ChildId == childId)
                    childList.Add(child);
            }
            contact.Childs = childList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an entity originally came from the database and has its own EntityKey properties populated, using *Add* to link it to another entity will change its EntityState to *Added*. Even though it is a preexisting entity, SaveChanges will create an insert command for this entity. You should consider using [*Attach*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896408.aspx) instead:

```
parent.ChildCollection.Attach(child);
```

Using the Attach method, you can define relationships between entities that already
exist in the ObjectContext but that have not been connected automatically.

Comment: I am using self-tracking entities (not sure how that may be effecting your comments)... but yes i am currently trying both parent.ChildCollection.Attach(child) as well as child.ParentCollection.Attach(parent) and in both cases EF is still adding new child objects/rows to the database.  This really has me stumped.

Comment: Can you post your code please? If you are using STE then Attach does not even exist on ChildCollection since it's of type `TrackableCollection<Child>`, so I'm not sure what you exactly are doing in there.